# SQLException caused by incorrect SQL syntax

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I have this code, that is supposed to execute a stored procedure and return its result.

```java
public static boolean finishOrderInteraction(int orderId, int departmentId){
        try{
            boolean result = true;
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("CALL finishOrderInteraction(?, ?, @result); SELECT @result AS Result;"); //returns true, if an SQLExeption accured during the procedure execution
            stmt.setInt(1, orderId);
            stmt.setInt(2, departmentId);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()){
                result = rs.getBoolean("Result");
            }
            con.close();
            return !result;
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Logger.Severe("Failed to update order status", e, "-");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My problem is, that this code produces this exception:

```
SQLException: (conn=122) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @result AS Result' at line 1
```

But when I try the same query via MySql Workbench everthing works as expected.

MySql Workbench query:

```sql
CALL finishOrderInteraction(126, 1, @result); SELECT @result AS Result;
```

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Why does the query work in MySql Workbench but not in my method?

Comment: You execute 2 sql queries using one prepared statement. You only need to perform 1 query with a java prepared statement. If you want to perform multiple queries, use the Batch processing method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your `OUT` parameters, and then access the values after calling update on the statement:

```java
public static boolean finishOrderInteraction(int orderId, int departmentId) {
    Boolean result = true;

    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);
        CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("CALL finishOrderInteraction(?, ?, ?)");
        stmt.setInt(1, orderId);
        stmt.setInt(2, departmentId);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN);

        stmt.executeUpdate();

        result = stmt.getBoolean(1);
        con.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.Severe("Failed to update order status", e, "-");
        return false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for your help. Unfortunately your answer was not quite on point, because your code has some flaws, but it definitely lead me to the right solution and I posted a new answer based on yours. At this point I have no idea if I should accept your answer or wait 2 days to accept my own. Maybe you can tell me what to do since you've clearly more experience on StackOverflow, then me.

Comment: Well tell me what the problems are, I'm happy to fix them.

Comment: You changed `PreparedStatement` to `CallableStatement` that was the first thing. The second is `result = rs.getBoolean(1);` instead of  `result = stmt.getBoolean(3);`. And you were right with this line: `return !result;` it has to be `return result;`

Comment: And I'm not sure if it works with `stmt.executeUpdate()` I used  `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(); `  and `while (rs.next()){result = rs.getBoolean(1);}` instead.

Comment: `not sure` isn't enough to make me edit the answer, unless you have tried the above and confirmed that it failed.  Maybe there is more than one way to call a prepared stored proc.

Comment: I can understand this. In that case I'll accept you answer as it is now, but won't delete my own answer just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim Biegeleisen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65213662/12520358) I was able to figure it out. It turned out, that the exception was a bit misleading, because even though there was a syntax error, this syntax error was not the reason why I didn't get the result I want.

The real problem was that I used `con.prepareStatement(...)` instead of `con.prepareCall(...)`, because `con.prepareCall(...)` creates a `CallableStatement`that let you register an out parameter. Thanks to this parameter there was no need for the second query `SELECT @result AS Result;` of my original statement, that caused the syntax error.

I ended up with this working code:

```java
public static boolean finishOrderInteraction(int orderId, int departmentId){
        try{
            Boolean result = true;
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);
            CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("CALL finishOrderInteraction(?, ?, ?)");
            stmt.setInt(1, orderId);
            stmt.setInt(2, departmentId);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.BOOLEAN);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()){
                result = rs.getBoolean(1);
            }
            con.close();
            return result;
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Logger.Severe("Failed to finish order interaction.", e, "-");
            return false;
        }
    }
```